# Swagger Authorize not receiving JWT Access Token

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using Windows Server 2012 ADFS v3.0 as the Identity Provider.  I have integrated Swagger using Swashbuckle for .Net Core API 2.2
As a result I must also use the authorizationCode flow in the OAuth2Scheme.

Step 1) Call Authorization URL and receive a code - **This is working** 
Step 2) Call Token URL and pass code as querystring parameter and receive a JWT Token - **This is Working**

I verified these two steps by monitoring the request and response in Fiddler.  
I also manually created my Requests in Postman and received the Token 
Within Chrome inspector the call to the Token is returning a success 200.  
I've been following this same type of flow for all of other internal applications. (First time using Swagger though)

The redirect to the TokenURL seems to work as I see the traffic of swagger/oauth-redirect.html which is just a redirect and then the page looks to automatically close

However for some reason the page gives a generic error message: 
Auth Error TypeError: Failed to fetch

The setup code
I am doing the configurations through my Startup.cs and not through a json configuration file.

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
{
   Type = "oauth2",
   Flow= "authorizationCode",
   AuthorizationUrl = "https://adfs.youridentityprovider.com/adfs/oauth2/authorize",
   TokenUrl= "https://adfs.youridentityprovider.com/adfs/oauth2/token",

});
```

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
   c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
   c.OAuthClientId("id linked in my Identity provider");
   c.OAuthClientSecret("swagger");
   c.OAuthAppName("app name linked in my Identity provider");
   c.OAuthRealm("identifier linked in my Identity provider");

   var qParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   qParams.Add("resource", "resource id");
   //This was needed because I kept getting an error message saying resource parameter was missing for the Authorization URL.  
   //I didn't like that it was adding a query string parameter to the Token URL call as well.  
   //But I verified that it was still working ok with this parameter  
   c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(qParams);
});
```

I haven't done the next step yet of passing this token to my API methods.  I figured this needs to happen after I can get authorized first.

Comment: Does this help - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-swagger-as-a-client-for-an-adfs-protected-api-49f9b4d773c

Comment: No didn't work.  This is also for ADFS v4 on Windows Server 2016, we are one version behind.  Maybe I will just wait on the server upgrade at end of the year